# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed error running Selenium tests with docker-compose

Tags: docker, selenium, google-chrome, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

while trying to run slenium tests from docker which we use in most projects i get this error saying chrome has crashed i 've both google chrome and chrome driver installed and working fine any help with this ?

```
  (node:231) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '1a84fd607b36', ip: '172.27.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.47-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x00400068e949 <unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
  (node:231) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '1a84fd607b36', ip: '172.27.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.47-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x00400068e949 <unknown>
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the ***incompatibility*** between the version of the binaries you are using as *`java.version: '1.8.0_292'`* and the error being:

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x00400068e949 <unknown>
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v95.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/notes.txt) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 95.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v95.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/notes.txt)).

Comment: JDK was the only missing part for my setup but  unfortunately , even after installing it i'm still can't run selenium tests and 'va the same error , btw i 'm using mac m1 i don't know if this is a common issue or not